# Clients for a REPL server do not display the server's input and output properly

Tags: node.js, stdin, read-eval-print-loop

I wrote a small REPL server and client for debugging the application I'm writing. When I input enough text to make it wrap to the next line in the terminal and press backspace though, it will display all the lines, not just the one that updated. I also can't move back to previous lines once I no longer have any characters to delete. There has to be a way to do this if node is reasonably sane, but I'm at a complete loss as to what to change. How can I make this work?

Edit: tab complete does not display until after hitting enter. Lines from history doesn't display in `process.stdin` at all, but will still be evaluated after sending them

**repl-client.js**

```
'use strict';

const net = require('net');

const socket = net.connect(8001, '0.0.0.0');
process.stdin.pipe(socket);
socket.pipe(process.stdout);

process.stdin.on('finish', () => {
    socket.destroy('');
});
```

**repl-server.js**

```
import * as babel from 'babel-core';
import net from 'net';
import repl from 'repl';
import vm from 'vm';

function extendContext(context) {
    // add vars I need to context
    return context;
}

function babelEval(input, filename) {
    let sanitizedInput = (input.startsWith('(') && input.endsWith(')'))
        ? input.slice(1, -1)
        : input;
    let code = babel.transform(sanitizedInput).code;
    return vm.runInThisContext(code, {filename});
}

export default function createREPLServer(port, hostname) {
    return net.createServer((socket) => {
        const _repl = repl.start({
            prompt: 'test> ',
            input: socket,
            output: socket,
            terminal: true,
            useColors: true,
            useGlobal: true,
            replMode: repl.REPL_MODE_STRICT,
            eval(input, context, filename, cb) {
                let err;
                let code;
                try {
                    code = babelEval(input.trim(), filename);
                } catch (e) {
                    err = e;
                }

                cb(err, code);
            }
        });
        _repl.on('reset', (context) => extendContext(context));
        _repl.on('exit', () => socket.end());

        extendContext(_repl.context);
    }).listen(8001, '0.0.0.0');
}
```

Comment: Likely some kind of line buffering involved. Try switching the program/terminal to raw mode? The alternative would be forgoing tab complete and `rlwrap`ing a `nc` instance

Comment: Running `process.stdin.setRawMode(true)` fixes most of this, but now pressing backspace when the input overlaps displays the entire input again with each press, rather than updating what's already there. Using `rlwrap` makes the output even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this in part with help of [小太郎](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359653/%E5%B0%8F%E5%A4%AA%E9%83%8E) and by adding a `readable` event handler to repl-server.js:

```
socket.on('readable', (chunk) => {
    socket.read(chunk);
});
```